# Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared ANGULAR

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

Good day everyone, I'm doing a personal project but at the moment of using:
import {NgForm} from '@ angular / forms';
The error appears, I've tried the command of "npm ci" and then re-installing node_modules, update the Node but the problem persists.
I did the respective validation in app.module.ts when importing the library but the problem still persists.
Any help, guidance or advice I really appreciate

```
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/forms/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/forms.js 27:12
Module parse failed: Identifier 'ɵngcc0' has already been declared (27:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|  */
| import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
> import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
| const NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new InjectionToken('NgValueAccessor');
|
```

These are the dependencies I am working with:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.32",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "angular-confirmation-popover": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^11.1.1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.10",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "md5-typescript": "^1.0.5",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-summernote": "^0.8.0",
    "notie": "^4.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "summernote": "^0.8.18",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
```

Comment: Is this your issue?https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41206

Comment: Yes, If it is the same problem, but I don't understand well how they did to solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution for this problem: When handling the Node 16.2.0 (Unsupported) version, it presented crashes.
The best way to solve it is to work on the stable version 14.17.3.

Answer (score 5):

Run `npm ci`

Then install packages again `npm install`

Comment: When I did, it completely corrupts everything.
So I tried to create a project again, replace the whole "src" folder but the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what solved it was to delete the node_modules folder and run the command `npm install`. After that the application started working again. Maybe this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you faced this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41198.
update your angular to at least 11.2.6, and the error will be gone

Comment: The error still persists
Angular CLI: 12.1.3        
Node: 16.2.0 (Unsupported) 
Package Manager: npm 7.20.1
OS: win32 ia32
Angular: 12.1.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Package                         Version
------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect      0.1201.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.3
@angular-devkit/core        12.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.3
@schematics/angular       12.1.3
rxjs    6.6.7
typescript        4.3.5